# How to change Xcode Install destination? (When installing iOS 4.x beta for example)

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am working on a project using iOS3.2 SDK and also want to test my app in iOS4.2 beta.
So I installed Xcode and 4.2 SDK but it replaces previous Xcode installation. Up until now it was ok since I was not busy with these two things. But now I need both.
How Do I change Xcode (with iOS SDK 4.2) install destination?

I was expecting a button "change install destination" during install but only installation disk partition is changeable. (No folder can be chosen).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you missed it in the installer because they made it hard to find. Once you pick the volume (your hard drive), you can Customize the installation, which lets you specify a location (/Developer-Beta or whatever you want). Unfortunately, you'll now have to reinstall other one again.

Comment: Is indeed really hard to find that!. But thanks I just found it.  ;)